# why i can't get factorial of a number? if i try it by taking else statement as return prod i get the correct answer

Tags: c

can i know why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int recfac(int );

main()
{
    int n,c;
    printf("enter a number ...\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    c=recfac(n);
    printf("the factorial of %d is %d ",n,c);
}

int recfac(int n)
{
    static int prod=1;

    if(n>1)
    {
        prod=prod*n;
        n--;
        return recfac(n);
    }
    else
        return;

    return prod;
}
```

Comment: can i know what's the problem with this code?

Comment: You aren't returning a value when `n > 1` is false.

Comment: @bigwillydos there is no need of returning a value , return in else statement makes the compiler to go to function call and as prod is static we can access it anywhere in the program.

Comment: also, `static int prod = 1;` is going to give you the wrong output for multiple calls to this function

Comment: @bigwillydos i want to call this function one time only,so i intentionally had taken it

Comment: with regard to your comment about not returning a value, your function is defined as returning type `int` so at a minimum this is a compiler warning. But if you are looking to cease recursive calls, this is not the way to go about doing it.

Comment: what's the way?

Comment: learning recursion, take a peak at the first section of the [wikipedia article on recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) it covers the exact problem you are trying to tackle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code

1. You have a return statement with no value within a function that is
   defined as returning type `int`
2. Your function is a recursive one yet you are using a static variable
   that will live through invocations, making the output invalid with
   multiple function calls
3. You are not handling the case where the input to your function is 0. This is the base case for what you are trying to achieve. You absolutely *must consider the base case* when writing a recursive function.

Code:

```
int recfac(int n)
{

    /* base case, ends recursive calls */
    if(!n) return 1;

    return n * recfac(n - 1);

}
```

Tested this code [here](http://tpcg.io/1VfCUx) for cases 1 - 9 and it gave the correct output.

EDIT: Also, `main` return type defaults to type `int` when no return type is specified and you have no return statement. You should include a `return 0;` statement to cease compiler warning.